# Why EF-6 migration are adding existing tables to new migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, migration, ef-code-first

I have added a new table to my model entity project with code first approach, now when I am creating new migration , it is adding existing tables to the new migration, I have researched in online but could not find any useful answer to this problem.

Comment: Have update databse?do you checked database?If Yes? You can delete exsiting table from migration then update databse

Comment: may be you have deleted last row of migrations_table

Comment: I have updated database already all those tables exist in my database, it was working fine a couple days before, when adding new migrations , it was adding only newly added classes to migration, but I don't know what gone wrong now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355195/entity-framework-trying-to-add-migration-of-tables-that-are-already-in-database

Comment: Just got some info from my team that probably migration history is messed up due to last merge conflicts from another branch which is causing issues. I have tried rolling back to previous migrations and updating database again, but nothing seems to help, issue is still there

Comment: Depending on volume of updates, you could just comment out the Up() code for the already existing items and apply the migration. Next migration will only be incremental changes. Also, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams)

Comment: Thanks  @mohsen  the link you provided solved my problem by creating an empty migration first, then doing any changes for new migration